# How to use esp_bt_gap_read_rssi_delta function to get bluetooth classic RSSI from ESP32?

Tags: c, bluetooth, rssi, esp32

Classic Bluetooth GAP API in ESP-IDF Framework has a function:

```
#include "esp_gap_bt_api.h"
esp_err_t esp_bt_gap_read_rssi_delta(esp_bd_addr_t remote_addr)
```

with the following description:

"*This function is called to read RSSI delta by address after connected. The RSSI value returned by ESP_BT_GAP_READ_RSSI_DELTA_EVT.*

*Return: ESP_OK : Succeed; ESP_FAIL: others*

*Parameters: remote_addr: - remote device address, corresponding to a certain connection handle.*"

Ok, what I am doing (after connection to the BT device):
define the structure, that I would think, will contain the result I need:

```
struct read_rssi_delta_param
{
  esp_bd_addr_t bda; /*remote bluetooth device address*/
  esp_bt_status_t stat; /*read rssi status */
  int8_t rssi_delta; /*rssi delta value in range -128 ~127*/
} read_rssi_delta; /*read rssi parameter struct */
```

and call the function:

```
esp_err_t err_code = esp_bt_gap_read_rssi_delta((uint8_t*)esp_bt_dev_get_address());
```

it returns err_code = ESP_OK (0, success) but read_rssi_delta struct contains just all zeros.

I feel I do something wrong because one more thing should be involved: that ESP_BT_GAP_READ_RSSI_DELTA_EVT (see description above). It's defined in a enumeration:

```
enum esp_bt_gap_cb_event_t //BT GAP callback events.
..... skip some
ESP_BT_GAP_READ_RSSI_DELTA_EVT //read rssi event
..... etc.
```

In some sources it's called "event", in others - "callback function" but nothing about how to use it!

So, the question is: **how to put all this stuff together to get RSSI from the device?**

Note: Bluetooth is classic, not BLE!

Comment: Just curious whether you gave up or found a solution somehow?

Comment: I gave up (or pretended I don't care :o)...

Answer (score 1):

After a few tries I got esp_bt_gap_read_rssi_delta() to work.

First thing to understand (in case you have not got it yet) is the callback/event thing. A callback function is a function in your code that will be called by the ESP-IDF when something special (an event) happens. You register your callback function by calling esp_bt_gap_register_callback() after initializing the bluetooth stack.

When you call esp_bt_gap_read_rssi_delta() (after connecting to the device), it returns immediately with an Ok or error status. The actual RSSI reading will be returned later by the framework calling your callback function.

The callback function has two parameters. The first identifies the event that happened, the second the data associated to the event. This second parameter is a pointer to one of the structures defined in the esp_bt_gap_cb_param_t union.

Here is some skeleton code (not testing return codes, etc) for the Arduino IDE, using the BluetoothSerial for the connection:

```
#include "esp_gap_bt_api.h"
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
byte addr[6] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  SerialBT.begin();
  esp_bt_gap_register_callback (gap_callback);
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
  if (SerialBT.hasClient()) {
    esp_bt_gap_read_rssi_delta (addr);
    delay (10000);    
  }
}

void gap_callback (esp_bt_gap_cb_event_t event, esp_bt_gap_cb_param_t *param) {
  if (event == ESP_BT_GAP_READ_RSSI_DELTA_EVT) {
    Serial.println (param->read_rssi_delta.rssi_delta);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you!
The other problems still remain:
1) To make it work I need to pass the MAC address of the peer device to esp_bt_gap_read_rssi_delta (addr) function. That makes sense: to get RSSI of connection to a device we need to know address of that device, right? But what is strange: if I pass any other random address, even 0:0:0:0:0:0, the param->read_rssi_delta.stat ("read rssi status") value will be ESP_BT_STATUS_SUCCESS in any case! Though the RSSI delta value (read_rssi_delta.rssi_delta) is real only if the address passed is actual MAC address of the paired device!

Comment: 2) The other problem is in the RSSI delta value itself^ it's "normal", good value is 0! That means that what ever RSSI I get - real or wrong, at first I get is as 0! And the only way to tell if the RSSI is real is to carry one device from the other away, or put something (sheet of foil, in my case) between the devices - then only you can see that RSSI value is changed - it drops down to -10, -20, etc. Note: the "read rssi status" reamins the same ESP_BT_ STATUS_SUCCESS in any case as I wrote above!

Comment: 3) These 2 above "problems" are not actually problems if you have the right ADDRESS OF THE PAIRED DEVICE. So there is the next question: **how to get this MAC address of the paired device?** Note: not the MAC address of the ESP32 device that is easy to get with esp_bt_dev_get_address() function, but REMOTE device's address.

Comment: You can get the MAC address of a SPP connected device through the ESP_SPP_SRV_OPEN_EVT event passed to a callback function registered by BluetoothSerial.register_callback() (I have no experience with other BT protocols). As the function name says, esp_bt_gap_read_rssi_delta will give deltas, not an actual value, I too find it a little limiting, but it is better than no information at all.

Comment: Thank you, dquadros, for pointing me to the Bluetooth class - there that function happens to be! With knowing that I immediately found the complete exaple on https://techtutorialsx.com/2018/12/11/esp32-arduino-serial-over-bluetooth-get-client-address/
Regarding RSSI deltas - does this mean that it is just difference between actual RSSI level and the previous RSSI value?! Which previous then? A second ago? A minute? At last callback call?

Comment: I tested my RSSI code and came to conclusion: ESP32 returns RSSI level (most probably) in dBm as folows: value from 0 to -20 (ESP_BT_GAP_RSSI_HIGH_THRLD - High RSSI threshold) means GOOD signal, then from -20 to -45 (ESP_BT_GAP_RSSI_LOW_THRLD - Low RSSI threshold) means signal strenth from 100% to 0%, below -45 threshold bluetoth connection usualy interrupts.

Answer (score 1):

So the final solution of my question (thanks to @dquadros) is:

```
//ESP32, Classic Bluetooth, SPP
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"
#include "esp_gap_bt_api.h"
#include <esp_spp_api.h>

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
byte rssi; //RSSI
byte addr[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0}; //to keep MAC address of the remote device

//RSSI callback function
void gap_callback (esp_bt_gap_cb_event_t event, esp_bt_gap_cb_param_t *param)
{
  if (event == ESP_BT_GAP_READ_RSSI_DELTA_EVT) rssi = param->read_rssi_delta.rssi_delta;
}

//SPP service callback function (to get remote MAC address)
void spp_callback (esp_spp_cb_event_t event, esp_spp_cb_param_t *param)
{
  if (event == ESP_SPP_SRV_OPEN_EVT) memcpy(addr, param->srv_open.rem_bda, 6);
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32");
  //register RSSI callback function:
  esp_bt_gap_register_callback (gap_callback);
  //register SPP service callback to get remote address:
  SerialBT.register_callback(spp_callback);
}

void loop()
{
  //when we need RSSI call this:
  esp_bt_gap_read_rssi_delta (addr); //now variable rssi contains RSSI level
  byte b = rssi; //etc....
}
```